# What details should I mention in my cover letter for a Schengen visa to the Netherlands?

Tags: schengen, conferences

I am planning to visit the Netherlands for a conference from 17th to 22nd July 2022. I am a Ph.D. student and an Indian citizen. What should I write in my cover letter which can prove my ties to my country? Also, please tell me what additional details to include in my cover letter. Also, will a fully paid ( but refundable) booking from a backpackers' hostel be considered sufficient proof of accommodation? (Stayokay Amsterdam OOST)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the search box at the top of the page, search for "Schengen visa ties home country." This will return other questions and answers here that addressed the "ties to home country" issues.

Comment: Is the conference near that hostel or readily accessible by train from Muiderpoort station?